# R code: why is my function producing no errors and no results?

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function and am having some problems.  My function doesn't create the new variable, and after running it there are no errors and no change as if I never ran it.  The code before the function works just fine and if I pass the arguments through the code directly (bypassing the function aspect of the code), it runs flawlessly.

Is there anything you think I'm missing? I have been looking at this for two days and have run out of ideas to try.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
path <- "C:/Documents/Data"
readFile <- paste(path,"/opps.csv",sep="")
oppsQty <- read.csv(file=readFile,sep=",")

oppsQty$Line.Created.date <- as.Date(as.character(oppsQty$Line.Created),
                                     "%m/%d/%Y")

opQty002.0084.01 <- oppsQty[oppsQty$Part=="002-0084-01",]

 productNumberData <- function(nameNum,prodNum){
    # CREATING YEAR VARIABLE #
    year2009 <- ifelse((nameNum$Line.Created.date <= 
                        as.Date("12/30/2009","%m/%d/%Y")),"2009","0")
    year2010 <- ifelse((nameNum$Line.Created.date > 
                        as.Date("12/30/2009","%m/%d/%Y")&
                        nameNum$Line.Created.date <= 
                        as.Date("12/30/2010","%m/%d/%Y")),"2010",year2009)
    year2011 <- ifelse((nameNum$Line.Created.date > 
                        as.Date("12/30/2010","%m/%d/%Y")&
                        nameNum$Line.Created.date <= 
                        as.Date("12/30/2011","%m/%d/%Y")),"2011",year2010)
    nameNum$line.YEAR <- ifelse((nameNum$Line.Created.date > 
                                as.Date("12/30/2011","%m/%d/%Y")&
                                nameNum$Line.Created.date <= 
                                as.Date("12/30/2012","%m/%d/%Y")),"2012",year2011)
 }
 productNumberData(opQty002.0084.01,"002-0084-01")
 #opQty002.0084.01$line.YEAR does not exist
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is the result of what is known as scoping. In any decent programming language, R included, variables are not valid globally. Instead, variables exist in a certain scope. The variable you are creating is part of the scope of the function. Therefore it is not found outside the function, where you try to use it, which leads to the error. Scoping rules in R do allow variables outside a function to be referenced, where the variable outside the function is used only when there is no variable with that name in the scope of the function.

Scoping reduces the dependency between pieces of code in a larger R script. In this way code in a function is far less likely to cause unwanted side effects in other functions.

The solution I would use is to put all the objects you create in a larger data structure, probably a `list`. The code would look something like:

```
spam = function(object_in) {
  A = f(object_in)
  B = g(object_in)
  list(A, B)
 }
result = spam(obj)
result[["A"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!
I created in the code above a version of a list called line.YEAR and attached it to the data set nameNum, however it does not exist in the data set even after I run the function. I understand the issue with scoping but does scoping still apply if I attach it to the data set within the function?

Comment: If you want to change an object outside the scope of the function you need to refer to it explicitly, i.e. `opQty002.0084.01$line.YEAR` inside the function. I would however advice against this as changing an external object from inside a function can have nasty side effects, especially if your script gets larger. It is better to let a function to have input arguments, and return an object.